# Building a classifier with J48

Tags: csv, weka, decision-tree

Weka is meant to make it very easy to build classifiers. There are many different kinds, and here **I want to use a scheme called “J48” that produces decision trees**.

Weka can read Comma Separated Values (.csv) format files by selecting the appropriate File Format in the Open file dialog.

I've created a small spreadsheet file (see the next image), saved it .csv format, and loaded it into Weka.

[image: weka]

The first row of the .csv file have the attribute names, separated by commas, which for this case is *classe real* and *resultado modelo*.

I've got the dataset opened in the Explorer.
If I go to the Classify panel, choose a classifier, open trees and click J48, i should just run it (I have the dataset, the classifier). (see the next image)
[image: j48]

**Well, it doesn't allow to press start.** (see the next image)
[image]

**What do I need to do to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look back at the Preprocess, you will see that resultado modelo is probably being treated as a numeric attribute.  J48 only works with nominal class attributes. (Predictor attributes can be numeric, as a commenter @nekomatic noted.)

You can change this by using a filter in the Preprocess tab. Choose the unsupervised attribute filter NumericToNominal and this will convert all your variables (or a subset of them) from numeric to nominal.  Then you should be able to run J48 just fine.

Comment: Eish awesome. Haven't reached the point of using filters until now. Appreciated for the help, it works

Comment: To be specific, J48 only works with nominal **class** attributes. You can build a J48 tree using numeric predictors perfectly well (as many of the example datasets supplied with Weka demonstrate) but the class you are trying to predict has to be nominal.